# optimization of an equation parameters using genetic sharp genetic algorithm

Tags: c#, optimization, geneticsharp

i have some data for example:

- x=1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- y=5, 4, 3, 2, 1
- z=1, 2, 1, 1, 3
- t=9, 12, 9, 9, 15.

i know that t=a*x+b*y+c*z. here i know a=1,b=1 and c=3 and i need to find them by genetic algorithm by Genetic Sharp. i wrote the below code but i get the boundary values all times of -100,-100,-100.
can you help me on it?

NOTE that i need the GA to search on a large boundary for example here i selected -100 to 100 for each of a,b and c. in real case i need to bound it to -100000 to 10000 for example. also i need the at least 10 fraction digits also.

```
double[] x = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
double[] y = new double[] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
double[] z = new double[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 3 };
double[] t = new double[] { 9, 12, 9, 9, 15 };
var selection = new EliteSelection();
var crossover = new UniformCrossover();
var mutation = new FlipBitMutation();
var fitness = new FuncFitness((c) =>
{
    var vals = (c as FloatingPointChromosome).ToFloatingPoints();
    double err = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Count(); i++)
    {
        err += Math.Pow((t[i] - (vals[0] * x[i] + vals[1] * y[i] + vals[2] * z[i])), 2);
    }
    return err;
});
var chromosome = new FloatingPointChromosome(
    new double[] { -100, -100, -100 },
    new double[] { 100, 100, 100 },
    new int[] { 64, 64, 64 },
    new int[] { 10, 10, 10 });
var population = new Population(100, 100, chromosome);
var ga = new GeneticAlgorithm(population, fitness, selection, crossover, mutation);
ga.Termination = new GenerationNumberTermination(300);
Console.WriteLine("GA running...");
ga.Start();
```

Comment: @giacomelli can you help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because the algorith wants to maximize the Fitness Function and in the way that you wrote it, the algo will find the worst possible values for your variables.

I changed the error calculation in the Fitness Function to

> err -= Math.Pow((t[i] - (vals[0] * x[i] + vals[1] * y[i] + vals[2] * z[i])), 2);

so now the maximum possible value for err is zero and the algorith will try to find the variable values for it.

Got very close results running this code, although couldn't get the exact ones.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem, by changing the fitness function and mutation the correct answer could be achieved using GeneticSharp. the modified code is as follows:

```
        //    x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        //    y = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
        //    z = 1, 2, 1, 1, 3
        //    t = 9, 12, 9, 9, 15.
        //    t = a*x + b*y + c*z
        //    a,b,c =???

        double[] x = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        double[] y = new double[] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        double[] z = new double[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 3 };
        double[] t = new double[] { 9, 12, 9, 9, 15 };

        var chromosome = new FloatingPointChromosome(
                   new double[] { -10, -10, -10 },
                   new double[] { 10.0, 10.0, 10.0 },
                   new int[] { 64, 64, 64 },
                   new int[] { 0, 0, 0 });

        var fitness = new FuncFitness((c) =>
        {
            var fc = c as FloatingPointChromosome;
            double err = 0;
            var values = fc.ToFloatingPoints();
            var pa = values[0];
            var pb = values[1];
            var pc = values[2];

            var fitness_e = 0.0;

            for (int i = 0; i < x.Count(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                var expected_result = t[i];
                var equations = (pa * x[i] + pb * y[i] + pc * z[i]);
                var diff = Math.Abs(equations - expected_result);
                fitness_e += diff;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return double.MinValue;
                }
            }
            return fitness_e * -1;
        });

        var population = new Population(100, 500, chromosome);

        var selection = new EliteSelection();
        var crossover = new ThreeParentCrossover();
        var mutation = new UniformMutation(true);

        var ga = new GeneticAlgorithm(population, fitness, selection, crossover, mutation);

        ga.Termination = new OrTermination(
          new GenerationNumberTermination(5000),
          new FitnessStagnationTermination(2000));

        ga.CrossoverProbability = 0.1f;
        ga.MutationProbability = 0.4f;
        ga.Reinsertion = new ElitistReinsertion();

        Console.WriteLine("GA running...");

        var latestFitness = 0.0;
        ga.GenerationRan += (sender1, e1) =>
        {
            var bestChromosome = ga.BestChromosome as FloatingPointChromosome;
            var bestFitness = bestChromosome.Fitness.Value;

            if (bestFitness != latestFitness)
            {
                latestFitness = bestFitness;
                var phenotype = bestChromosome.ToFloatingPoints();

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Generation {0}:  {1},{2},{3} fitness: {4}",
                    ga.GenerationsNumber,
                    phenotype[0],
                    phenotype[1],
                    phenotype[2],
                    bestFitness
                );
            }
        };

        ga.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("GA End");
```